# How to hide webui-popover when not in focus (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have a dynamically populated table and i've appended a webui-popover to each table row. For it to be visible, one has to click on an link item. I'm using the manual trigger to control its visibility.

My problem however is that when one popover is visible, i'm unable to hide it when i click outside the pop area. The documentation allows a dismissable to be set to true but this doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

```
 //Sample html
 <tr>
  <td>name</td>
    <td><a class="more" id="'.$id.'" data-fid="'.$fid.'" data-uplid="'.$uplid.'"  href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a></td>
   </tr>
```

Javascript for showing the dynamic popover

```
var more = document.getElementsByClassName('more');

for (var i = 0; i < more.length ; i++) {

    var fid, uplid;

    more[i].onclick = function(){

     fid = this.dataset.fid;
     uplid = this.dataset.uplid;

     //Popover
     $('#' + fid).webuiPopover({
      content: function(){
       var html = '<div id="pop-content">';
        html += '<a href="core/upload/'+fid+'/'+uplid+'" class="collection-item active">Edit</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        return html;
      },
      trigger: 'manual',
      dismissible: true,
      style: 'v2',
      placement: 'bottom-left',
      animation: 'pop',
      width: '180',
      cache: false
     });

    //Once the values have been passed, show the popover
    $('#' + fid).webuiPopover('show');
  }
}
```

I need to make it hide once the mouse is not in target, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use:

```
trigger: 'click'
```

Besides, remove the 'onclick' event listener and the function encapsulating your popover content:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/6xk6vcjx/)

Comment: hi @R.Costa, i tried your approach but it only show first id for all. i edited your fiddle by adding two more rows to the table but the output is usually the last item

Comment: You're right, Mueyiwa. I didn't notice but that's because the html content is encapsulated in a function. I've updated my answer and my code accordingly.

Comment: Nice, but what exactly did you change tho. code looks the same to me

Comment: I just updated the field 'content', assigning the html directly instead of the function.